# Does a uniform changing magnetic field necessarily induce a uniform electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I don't understand why, using the curie principle, a uniform (but changing in time) magnetic field doesn't induce a uniform electric field. For example, if I take an infinte cylinder plunged into a magnetic field that only depends on time, The induced electric field depends on time but also on the distance from the cylinder's axis.

Generally, Can someone explain how symmetries and invariance work when the source is not a charge density but a changing current/magnetic field?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "Curie principle"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie%27s_Principle